# Why docker layer is not cached?

Tags: docker, caching

I have Dockerfile which have next command:

```
RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && perlbrew install $PERL_VERSION
```

Here layers start to rebuild:

```
Step 12/27 : RUN echo -e "\nif [ -f /opt/perlbrew/etc/bashrc ]; then\n\tsource /opt/perlbrew/etc/bashrc\nfi\n" >> /root/.bash_profile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b18437df38fb
Step 13/27 : RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && perlbrew install $PERL_VERSION
 ---> Running in 3b76e5d4ae0a

Fetching perl 5.24.1 as /opt/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.24.1.tar.bz2
Download http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.24.1.tar.bz2 to /opt/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.24.1.tar.bz2
Installing /opt/perlbrew/build/perl-5.24.1/perl-5.24.1 into /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1
```

Why cached layer is not used for this command?

**UPD**
The docker file:

```
FROM centos:latest

ARG PERLBREW_ROOT=/opt/perlbrew
ARG PERL_VERSION=5.24.1
ARG MONKEYMAN_DIR=/opt/monkeyman

RUN yum -y install yum-plugin-ovl
RUN yum -y upgrade
RUN yum -y install perl
RUN yum-builddep -y perl
RUN yum install -y bzip2 zip which
RUN yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
RUN curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
RUN echo -e "\nif [ -f /opt/perlbrew/etc/bashrc ]; then\n\tsource /opt/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
\nfi\n" >> /root/.bash_profile
RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && perlbrew install $PERL_VERSION
RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && perlbrew switch $PERL_VERSION
RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && perlbrew install-cpanm
RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && cpanm Carton
```

no arguments provided when build

**UPD**

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 07f3374/1.13.1
```

Comment: How is `$PERLBREW_ROOT` defined? Could you provide an example that allows to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Something before this line has probably changed.

Comment: @DavidMaze: no, step 12 uses cache. See updated question

Comment: @Behe: Example provided. See updated question

Comment: Can you include the output of two build commands run consecutively on the same host?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I tried it out using Docker 18.09.3: it uses the cache correctly when I build it for the second time. What docker version do you have?

Comment: @Behe: My docker version is 1.13.1